# MAvericks default PHP extension error

Tags: php, osx-mavericks

Trying to run via command line a PHP script. I am getting warnings and wondering how to fix them.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-    debug-non-zts-20100525/php_curl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts- 20100525/php_curl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_mysqli.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_mysqli.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_xmlrpc.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_xmlrpc.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

When I look in that directory of /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/, all I see is

```
xdebug.so
```

Thanks for any support you guys can give.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: Yeah I think I figured out that the extensions are not installed but how to install them is what I am trying to figure out. Homebrew?

Comment: What PHP version are you using? I'm just trying to write up an answer. Use `phpversion()`.

Comment: looks really odd, there are no `.dll` files on OSX, mavericks or no mavericks

Comment: PHP 5.4.24 is the version I am running

Comment: How did you download PHP? Are you using the default PHP? Cause as mentioned above `.dll` isn't Mac...

Comment: I just enabled PHP via the httpd.conf, so I am using the default version that cam with the mac

Comment: That is kinda weird that it would be looking for dll

Comment: I'm looking through my php.ini right now and those `.dll` files are under Windows Extensions. Make sure they're all commented with `;`. Are they?