# Issue while php upgrade 5.3 to 5.6

Tags: php, installation, php-5.6

I have *upgraded php from 5.3 to 5.6*. After this i am getting below warning and command doesn't run.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>
> '/opt/applications/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcache.so'
>   - /opt/applications/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcache.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0

I am on `REHL 5.10 server`. What do I need to do in this case to resolve this issue.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library?rq=1

Comment: Do you have access to your php.ini file?

Comment: Yes i do have access to ini file

Comment: How exactly did you upgrade? You may have to recompile/install your extensions as well, if those haven't been upgraded in the process.

Comment: Is this still an issue, or have you updated to a newer version of PHP? hopefully you have, given [supported-versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)