# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_openssl.dll'

Tags: dll, yii2

I am using Yii2, after the migration of project from localhost to linux server. It showing this error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I know its a windows library and don't know where should I check?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: phpinfo() showing that openssl.dll is enabled but am getting the same error.