# Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php

I am currently hosting on 1und1.de. my codes work on localhost but upon uploading it on the shared hosting server i got the following errors:

```
Warning: Unknown: open(C:\xampp\tmp/sess_bnt91ftgq6s4obn2684fud47p5, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (C:\xampp\tmp) in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_bz2.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_bz2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_curl.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mbstring.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_exif.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_exif.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gd2.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gd2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gettext.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_gettext.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysql.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysqli.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_openssl.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_pdo_sqlite.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_soap.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sockets.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sockets.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite3.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_sqlite3.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_xmlrpc.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_xmlrpc.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext/php_xsl.dll' - C:\xampp\php\ext/php_xsl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Cannot open 'C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0
```

What does these errors mean. does these errors have something to do with my hosting provider?

Comment: I think that these errors mean that you should change your hosting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: Basically these are apache server libraries. Mostly present in major packages. The package on this hosting is corrupt or something.

Comment: In case someone is having similar problems I've answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as though you've probably copied your `php.ini` configuration file directly from your system to your hosting server. Don't do that. The data in your configuration file is specific to your XAMPP installation; this is not appropriate for the web server, and is causing these errors because the files referenced in your configuration do not exist on the server.

Answer (score 9):

I had this error locally with this message:

> Warning: Cannot open "\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini" for reading in
> Unknown on line 0

By changing this line of `php.ini` file :

```
browscap="\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
```

to this:

```
browscap="C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
```

the error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people here are not as they could be...

For whatever reason, your php.ini is mis-configured.

One thing to note that all those missing files are actually Windows files (*.dll) on Linux these would likely be *.so files.  I'm assuming your hosting on a Linux server.

First find your php.ini file.  If you have command line access via SSH, you can try running:

```
php --ini
```

if not you make a simple script, call it test.php like so:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Upload the file and run it, something like:

http://www.yoursite.com/test.php

Among the information provided will be the path to php.ini

Once you find it, one option is to edit it and comment out all those extensions, by putting a ";" in front of the line.

Another option is to check if the *.so files exist.  Look for them under /usr/lib/php.  If they exist, edit your php.ini file to have all those extension end in .so instead of .dll

Finally, if they don't exist, you could install them by using apt-get or yum.  An example:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```