# PHP not finding DB2 extension

Tags: php, db2, vagrant

I have a vagrant box set up for development. It has been running fine for months, but I recently ran `vagrant box update` since it'd been nagging me to update, and naturally it's now broken.

The problem is with PHP startup. It can't find the DB2 `so` file:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/ibm_db2.so' - libdb2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

However, the file is there:

```
~$ sudo find / -name '*db2.so'
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/ibm_db2.so
```

Any idea what's up with this error?

Comment: the file ISN'T there. error is for `libdb2.so.1`, and you found `ibm_db2.so`.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5282287/1399696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I updated my vagrant box the PHP extension was installed correctly but could no longer find the DB2 headers. I had to `sudo pecl uninstall ibm_db2` then follow the instructions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php#113330) to download and install the DB2 headers. Finally I reinstalled the pecl extension using `sudo pecl install ibm_db2` and I was back in business.