# Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ ftp.dll'

Tags: php, xampp

PHP **Warning:**

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_
>   ftp.dll' - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on
>   line 0

Comment: @sagar43 can you post the solution or  link ?.

Comment: Check this if it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by commenting out **;extension=php_ftp.dll** in xampp\php\php.ini