# Unable To Load Dynamic Library /usr/lib64/php/modules/php_soap.dll

Tags: php, centos

When I execute file in mremote, then it shows this warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_soap.dll'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Answer (score 1):

Go TO  php.ini file:

```
extension_dir = "\xampp\php\ext"
browscap = "\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
```

to(add your xampp path )

```
extension_dir = "D:\xampp\php\ext"
browscap = "D:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can get the 'Unable to load dynamic library' message for a couple of different reasons:

1. You have enabled a module in php.ini but PHP can't find the dll file (either it doesn't exist, or it is in the wrong directory).
2. The dll file was compiled for the wrong architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit) or the wrong threading model (e.g. a thread-safe DLL being used on a non-thread-safe version of PHP).  Or maybe even the wrong platform (Linux/Windows).
3. The dll has some dependencies that couldn't be found.  For example, you may need some additional .dll files to be put in a location that PHP can find them (e.g. in the main PHP directory).

In your case, it looks like scenario #2 applies.  Based on the path/filename you've posted, it looks like you are trying to load a Windows .dll version of the extension on a Unix-like architecture.

With the brief information you've given I'm not sure I can help much more than that, but hopefully the above pointers should help you diagnose the problem a bit better.