# PHP : broken links, errors, cms

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I uploaded an old website and tested it, got this problem :

> Latest from blog
>
> Uncaught Exception
>
> String could not be parsed as XML Trace in execution order:
>
> require('/home/bp2mhold/io.bp2mholding.com/cms/app/main.php')  on line
>   113 in /home/bp2mhold/io.bp2mholding.com/index.php    main()  on line
>   210 in /home/bp2mhold/io.bp2mholding.com/cms/app/main.php
>         Page→_executeLayout()  on line 200 in /home/bp2mhold/io.bp2mholding.com/cms/app/main.php
>            eval()  on line 388 in /home/bp2mhold/io.bp2mholding.com/cms/app/models/Page.php
>               getWPLatestPost('http://www.iogi.com/blog/feed/')  on line 39 in /home/bp2mhold/io.bp2mholding.com/cms/app/models/Page.php(388) :
>   eval()'d code
>                  SimpleXMLElement→__construct('http://www.iogi.com/blog/feed/', 16384,
>   true)  on line 20 in
>   /home/bp2mhold/io.bp2mholding.com/cms/plugins/aggregator/index.php
>                      Exception was thrown on line 20 in /home/bp2mhold/io.bp2mholding.com/cms/plugins/aggregator/index.php

After following the links to find the true mistake, I couldn't find the old link (www.iogi.com/blog/feed), it wasn't anywhere.

I went then in the error.php to see if there was any problem and had this line (like 30 times)

> [29-Nov-2016 05:43:42 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/imagick.so' -
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/imagick.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0

I checked the info.php file and had this :

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Nothing more, nothing less.

So my questions are, how can I find the source of that link, and what is that missing file that should have loaded ?

Any help will be apprecied :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: I was on that page just before posting, I checked the solution they gave there, not working for me

Comment: Have you definitely got `imagick.so` installed on your server/does it say so when you do `phpinfo()`?

Comment: I don't have it.
I found other pages about how to install it (complicated, 3 differents files)
I also find someone who told to just pass it as a comment so it don't load... 

Which one is the best solution ? Can it work without this imagick.so file ?