# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so'

Tags: php, linux, pdo, debian, zts

I've recompiled PHP sources to enable zts but now PDO no longer works, when I try to execute a script with a pdo instantiation i get this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

and when I try `php -i` i get the same error.

I think that maybe my extension dir is no longer what it used to be before I recompiled php sources.

So i tried to do `ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysql.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/` but it also failed

Comment: [This question doesn't have an excepted answer, but some of the suggestions may be useful for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar errors with Codeigniter 3 and Ubuntu 14.04.

1. Check if your PDO extension is installed.
2. Or try comment out line of that extension in php.ini file (this is how I'm get rid of this error) .