# Cannot Run php in windows command line, works OK in linux

Tags: php, windows, command-line

The other answers to this question do not seem to work or be relevant.

I have a script (mailPipe.php) which parses a file (mail.raw) into a MySQL database.

In linux, I can run it as follows:

```
cat mail.raw | ./mailPipe.php
```

I am trying to run this in Windows

I have verified php.exe is in my PATH

The syntax I am using is

```
php.exe "C:\xampp\php\MailPipe.php" -- c:\xampp\php\mail.raw
```

When I run this in the php directory I get multiple error statements saying various .dll files cannot be found, such as:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\php\ext\php_pdo_sq
lite.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

I do not get this when I put the files into the PEAR directory, but it just does not work

Frustratingly, I noticed from looking at the MySQL table that the insert statement worked correctly twice but I stupidly did not note the correct syntax when it happened, had been trying many permutations of the command.

Looking at comments here and other posts, I have tried using the "-f" switch, "-r", and "-a", all to no avail.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

May be your script need some php extension, that did not loaded ('PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library').

Try to fix this errors, see [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)
and may be script will  start working.