# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so:

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel, ubuntu

How to fix this message ?

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line
>   0

Comment: you need to instal GD library depending on your PHP version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to install MCrypt module for php5. 
Follow the step

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

This might happen when you remove php pakage improperly
Hope this will resolve your problem