# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so'

Tags: php, composer-php, mpdf

This is the error message i get on try to install the [MPDF/MPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf).

```
$ composer create-project mpdf/mpdf --prefer-dist
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on 
runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
```

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>       The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL
>       operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>       error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
>       Failed to enable crypto
>       failed to open stream: operation failed

I don't know what to do to proceed, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

i think this could help you.
Seems you are not the first guy with this problem.^^
[PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561354/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib-php-20151012)

Comment: Hoho, i will see. Thx

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question, i can't see them =/

Comment: Which Version is your php?

Comment: Because it's min 5.6

Comment: I getting this error again :O **~$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group**

Comment: my php version is broken !?

Comment: looks so, try to reinstall it.