# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library: Linux version is centos6.7

Tags: php, mysqli

> **PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:** Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mysql.dll'
>   - /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mysql.dll:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> **Warning: PHP Startup:**
>    Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mysql.dll'
>   - /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mysql.dll:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mysqli.dll'
>   - /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mysqli.dll:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> **Warning: PHP Startup:**  Unable to load dynamic library 
>   '/usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mysqli.dll'
>    - /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_mysqli.dll:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown 
>   on line 0

Comment: I think this might be the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: you are under linux flavor and trying to load a windows-way extension ?

Comment: Check what @hassan wrote. Dude you use Linux, but load Windows libraries?

Comment: Make sure your looking at the right php.ini file, there are different ones for the CLI and web versions of php.  Check a `php -i | grep cli` to find which file your using.