# Call to undefined function printer_list()

Tags: php, wamp, php-printer

I'm getting Call to undefined function `printer_list()` cuz my **php_printer.dll** isn't working and in the error log I'm getting PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library.

`c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_printer.dll`

I searched the entire web for php_printer.dll that works with php 5.6.31 and I didn't find it, I'm working with wampserver 3.1 on windows 7 can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: WAMPServer does not ship with `php_printer.dll` so where did you get your `php_printer.dll` from? And where did you put it when you got hold of it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I downloaded from here, my dear. https://github.com/gimjudge/php and it says php 5.6.30 while I have php 5.6.31 so maybe that's why it's not working, however I can't find a file that works and it's so rare and I really need it

Comment: And I put it in "c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [one issue](https://github.com/gimjudge/php/issues/1) on that git repo I see that gimjudge has complied these DLL's for 32 PHP only. Their reasoning being that until PHP7 the 64bit PHP versions were actually only experimental. PHP only became truly 64 bit as of PHP7.0

So to use this dll you would have to install the 32bit version of WAMPServer. Then you will probably have no problems activating this DLL.

You can download the 32bit version of WAMPServer 3 [from here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Its the backup repo and much easier to see what you are doing and which version you are downloading than the normal SourceForge repo.

Make sure you have backed up all you site(s) and databases before installing the 32bit WAMPServer.

However it is possible to install the 32bit AND 64bit WAMPServer on the same PC as the default folder names are different (C:\wamp or C:\wamp64) the Apache and MySQL service names are also different (wampapache or wampapache64) and (wampmysqld or wampmysqld64)

Although its not a good idea to start both at the same time as this will use a lot of memory for no good reason.

Comment: It worked!, thank you so much my dear. I really appreciate it