# php not finding php_protobuf_ts and php_curve25519_ts

Tags: php, dll, xampp

I am using php 7.1.12 on a windows PC, i have tried to install php_protobuf_ts.dll and php_curve25519_ts.dll extensions to php i keep getting this error

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp2\php\ext\php_protobuf_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp2\php\ext\php_curve25519_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0

I am getting this error despite confirming that the above extensions exist on the specified directory. Please help, i have tried everything

Comment: please Check below Link it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library

Comment: When i go to the default directory the extension actually exists