# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_sqlite3.dll'

Tags: php, sqlite, yii2

I have reccuring found this error.

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_sqlite3.dll' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_sqlite3.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library

Comment: could be multiple reasons , and empty line in the `php.ini` for the `extension=''` and invalid path to the extension, or if the path exists there might rights issue.