# Unable to load "pdo_sqlite"

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am working on a website which needs to interact with an SQLite database. This is my first project using PHP and I'm running into some issues. So far I have:

*config.php*:

```php
...
$connection = new SQLiteConnection();
$connection->connect();
```

And in *SQLiteConnection*, `$connection->connect()` does pretty much this:

```php
try {
    $rootDir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
    $this->pdo = new PDO("sqlite:".$rootDir.self::DATABASE_PATH);
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Exception: '".$e->getMessage()."' at line ".$e->getLine();
}
```

However each time I run `config.php` I get the following error:

> Exception: 'could not find driver' at line 22

This is the line where I initialise a `PDO`.

---

I have tried lots of solutions:

- Purging and reinstalling `php-common`, `php-sqlite3`, and others
- Uncommenting these lines in my `php.ini` file (in /etc/php/7.2/cli):

```php
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3
```

- Uncommenting and setting an extension directory in the same `php.ini` file:

```php
sqlite3.extension_dir = "ext"
```

- Restarting the apache2 service (`sudo service apache2 restart`)

When I run `php -m` I do get the modules in the list, but with a warning:

```
$ php -m
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
...
PDO
pdo_sqlite
...
sqlite3
...
```

But when I look into the contents of the directory, those files seem to be present:

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/php/20170718
total 6372
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar  1 11:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 Mar  1 11:38 ..
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  113048 Feb 11 15:55 pdo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31096 Feb 11 15:55 pdo_sqlite.so
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   52648 Feb 11 15:55 sqlite3.so
...
```

When I look into its parent directory, I see:

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/php/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Mar  1 11:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 144 root root 4096 Mar  1 11:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Mar  1 11:40 20170718
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Mar  1 11:38 7.2
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 4845 Jan 17  2018 php-helper
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 9534 Jan 17  2018 php-maintscript-helper
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 2922 Jan 17  2018 sessionclean
```

Could the issue be because of both `20170718` and `7.2` are present (I'm not really sure of the difference)? The `7.2` directory doesn't have any of the `.so` files though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On restarting my computer (and thus the IDE I am using, IntelliJ), I received a different error when running the `config.php` file - that I needed to install `php-cgi`.

I did so and no longer received the exception when running `config.php`. I suppose I already solved that problem and it just required an **IDE restart** to apply it.

---

The second issue, that still remained, was the warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'sqlite3' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

And I resolved this using the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library):

> It means there is an extension=... or zend_extension=... line in one of your php configuration files (php.ini, or another close to it) that is trying to load that extension.

In trying to find a solution earlier, I had uncommented a few lines in the `php.ini` file. Simple commenting them back fixed the issue!

Answer (score -1):

In case of php 7.4 on Windows, you must include the directory where libsqlite3.dll resides in the path.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php

Comment: Please share more details. The given file structure lets me think that Windows is in no way part of the problem

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29950955)