# Unable to install Contao CMS on localhost in Mac using terminal

Tags: php, contao

I'm facing problem on installing Contao on my Mac.
I run the command that I get from [here](https://docs.contao.org/dev/getting-started/initial-setup/)

`composer create-project contao/managed-edition`

but I am getting this error

```
hasnainshafqat@Hasnains-MBP project % composer create-project contao/managed-edition

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl), /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so)) in Unknown on line 0
Creating a "contao/managed-edition" project at "./managed-edition"
Installing contao/managed-edition (4.9)
  - Installing contao/managed-edition (4.9): Loading from cache
Created project in /Users/hasnainshafqat/contao/project/managed-edition
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - contao/newsletter-bundle 4.9.2 requires contao/core-bundle 4.9.2 -> satisfiable by contao/core-bundle[4.9.2].
    - contao/newsletter-bundle 4.9.1 requires contao/core-bundle 4.9.1 -> satisfiable by contao/core-bundle[4.9.1].
    - contao/newsletter-bundle 4.9.0 requires contao/core-bundle 4.9.0 -> satisfiable by contao/core-bundle[4.9.0].
    - contao/core-bundle 4.9.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - contao/core-bundle 4.9.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - contao/core-bundle 4.9.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for contao/newsletter-bundle ^4.9 -> satisfiable by contao/newsletter-bundle[4.9.0, 4.9.1, 4.9.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I've enable the extension from php.ini file but still I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6C-xrjztoQ) of my installation . please let me know what I've to fix 
php version is

```
hasnainshafqat@Hasnains-MBP project % php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl), /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Feb 29 2020 02:50:36) ( NTS )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: Did you forget to restart the web server?

Comment: I tried but it's not very helpful. I'm stuck right now. which service I need to restart ? I am installing through composer and composer already installed globally. I tried to restart my laptop but it does not work

Comment: You need to restart Apache or Nginx after enabling extention

Comment: The installed `intl` extension is incompatible to your installed php version.
Check your `php.ini` for the extension path and verify that it is the correct one (have a look in `/usr/lib/php/extensions/` if there might be multiple available and use the correct one).
Restarting apache won't fix your issue, as you are using php from CLI here and therefore the extension will get loaded upon each invocation.