# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pgsq in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have been having an issue in yii2 deployment . My System keeps returning an error message from time to time when api functions are called. Any ideas on how to solve this will be appreciated.

```
   name "PHP Core Warning"
   message:PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pgsq' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pgsq: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   code 32
   type "yii\\base\\ErrorException"
   file "Unknown"
   line 0
   stack-trace  [ "#0 [internal function]: yii\\base\\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()", "#1   
   {main}" ]
   0    "#0 [internal function]: yii\\base\\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()"
   1    "#1 {main}"
```

fr

Comment: Does the directory or file exist?

Comment: i Searched and it does not exist.

Comment: Then it seems your server does not have it installed or it is in a diffrent path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

Comment: @CodeSpirit no. the issue is that I don't even have any library like pgsq. I have commented out pdo_pgsql etc but It isn't working. I don't even know which package is pgsq because I haven't seen it before.

Comment: There can be multiple config files for php and it is common that people change the wrong ones (use `php --ini` or `phpinfo()` to find them). pgsql is PHPs library for PostgreSQL and the message shows that you still try to load it in your ini.

Comment: how do I know I know the right file to change because when I use php --ini, I see so many files

Comment: Check [PHP - The configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282264/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library) for info. All files work but you have to consider in which order they are loaded (php.ini first and then in alnum order).

Comment: I actually discovered that the issue is bigger than I thought. I can't install anything using apt-get or dpkg. when I run php -v for example, I get a clear warning to my error PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_pgsql (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_pgsql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_pgsql.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0 but I don't still know how to fix this. have been googling around